# Rails checkbox selectable area

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Right now my rails checkboxes are only toggled if you click on the checkbox; nothing happens if I click the text associated with the checkbox. Is there a way to get the checkbox to toggle if you click the TEXT as well?

```
<% @books.each do |b| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "books[]", b.book %><%= b.book %><br />
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was tricky because of the [] that are needed to work with checkbox collections. Just do the following:

View:

> ```
> <% @books.each do |b| %>
>   <%= check_box_tag "books[#{b.id}]", b.book %>
>   <%= label_tag "books[#{b.id}]", b.book %>
>   <br />
> <% end %>
> ```

Then in the controller access the parameter by it's `values`. Otherwise it looks like 135=>Book1. Use `values` to get just Book1

> params[:books].values

Or an **even easier way** is to simply wrap the `check_box_tag` with a `<label>` like so:

```
...
<label><%= check_box_tag "books[]", b.book %></label>
...
```

Notice now you don't even need to worry about the unique id via `#{b.id}` so the controller code can be changed back to

```
params[:books]  # notice the .values is removed
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the text in a [label tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) which points at the ID of the checkbox. Rails has a [label](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-label_tag) helper for it.

Comment: How do I use a label tag when my checkbox id is `books_`?

Comment: Your checkboxes need to have unique IDs for this to work, and for your code to be valid. You may need to set the id of each checkbox so that the labels can be set to reference them, since you're not running this off a model or using nested attributes.